# HTML page not rendering

Tags: html, rendering

Having problem with one of my development work that from time to time the page is rendering as text.  Look at the http header and I cannot see anything wrong.  Can someone give me a helping eye.

Thanks

```
            0000

            HTTP/1.1 200 OK
            Date: Fri, 09 Dec 2016 13:15:49 GMT
            Content-Length: 5621
            Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
            Content-Language: en
            X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1



            <!DOCTYPE html>















            <html ng-app="myApp">
            <head>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"> 
                <title>RunDetails</title>







                <script type="text/javascript" src="/environment/resources/js/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/environment/resources/dev/bootstrap-3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/environment/resources/js/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/environment/resources/js/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-animate.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/environment/resources/js/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-resource.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/environment/resources/js/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.3.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/environment/resources/jquery-ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/environment/resources/js/angular-strap/2.3.1/angular-strap.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/environment/resources/js/angular-strap/2.3.1/tooltip.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/environment/resources/js/angular-strap/2.3.1/angular-strap.tpl.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/environment/resources/js/underscore-min.js"></script>

                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/environment/resources/dev/css/em.css" />
                 <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/environment/resources/dev/bootstrap-3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
                <!-- Bootstrap theme -->
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/environment/resources/dev/bootstrap-3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />

                <!-- jQuery/Bootstrap JS -->
                <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div id="envmon-header">
                        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1" id="logo">
                    <img src="/environment/resources/dev/img/flight.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6" id="headertitle">
                            <!-- <h1><a href="/environment/home">Environment Monitoring</a></h1>  -->
                            <h1>Environment Monitoring</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                    <li><h2><a href="/environment">Run A REPORT</a></h2></li>
                    <li class="dropdown" >
                        <h2 class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><a href="#">CONFIGURATION <b class="caret"></b></a></h2>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu1" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="/environment/componentsearch">Component Search</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/environment/componentgroupsearch">Component Group Search</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/environment/timeperiodsearch">Time Period Search</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>  
            </div>  

                    </div>

                    <div id="envmon-body" >


                <div id="angularTestPage" class="theme-showcase row" ng-controller="RunDetailsPageController">
                <!-- Error container. This should be populate with right error message on execution. -->
                    <div ng-cloak class="row">
                        <div ng-cloak class="alert-danger" ng-repeat="error in headerErrors">
                            {{error.message}}
                        </div>
                        <div ng-cloak class="alert-warning" ng-repeat="warning in headerWarnings">
                            {{warning.message}}
                        </div>
                        <div ng-cloak class="alert-info" ng-repeat="info in headerInfos">
                            {{info.message}}
                        </div>
                        <div ng-cloak class="global-error alert alert-success header-errors" ng-repeat="success in headerSuccesses">
                            {{success.message}}
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv    Actual Content Start Here vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv -->
                    <div id="content-title" class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 pageTitle align-left">Test Run Details</div>   
                        <div class="col-md-6" >
                            <input type="submit" ng-click="exportButtonClicked()" id="btnExport" class="styled-button pull-right" value="EXPORT" /> 
                        </div>              
                    </div>

                    <div id="run-detailsid" class="row">
                        <div id="" name="" class="row table-header-row" >
                            <div class="col-md-1">Component</div>
                            <div class="col-md-1">Status</div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">Test Name</div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">Service</div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">Operation</div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">Created Date</div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="" name="" class="row table-detail-row-wrap" ng-repeat="runDetail in runDetails">
                            <div class="col-md-1 table-cell centered">{{runDetail.componentName}}</div>
                            <div class="col-md-1 table-cell centered">
                                <div ng-show="runDetail.testLogId != ''">
                                    <a href="" ng-click="runSelectedTestId(runDetail.testLogId);">
                                        <img ng-src="{{runDetail.status == 2 ? redCircleImageLocation : greenCircleImageLocation}}" border="0" >
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 ">{{runDetail.testName}}</div>
                            <div class="col-md-2 ">{{runDetail.service}}</div>
                            <div class="col-md-2 ">{{runDetail.operation}}</div>
                            <div class="col-md-2 ">{{runDetail.createdDate}}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div>&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 centered">runId = {{runDetails[0].runId}} </div>                  
                </div>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="/environment/resources/js/controllers/rundetails.js"></script>

                    </div>

                    <div id="envmon-footer">
                        <div class="row">
                <div id="footer">

                </div>
            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: The `0000` certainly does not belong there and would explain why the browser renders things like that. So the question is: where does that come from? Looks like some premature output of some script maybe?

Comment: Have you tried reducing the problem by removing part of the html and see if the problem remains?